# Method to sum and reverse a single input in Java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //call for input
    System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] num = new int[3];
    int val = in.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++);
    
    System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + num[0] + num[1]+ num[2]);
    System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + num[2] + num[1]+ num[0]);
    
}
```

The input is suppose to be any number bigger than 10 but when I give it
Any number,it gives me the same 000?

Comment: Notice the `;` right after your `for`. It is making the `for` loop have an empty body, exactly like `for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) { }`.

Comment: Even after the correction @acdcjunior mentions, only the first line will be evaluated unless you use curly braces around the body of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with your code:

You never put user input inside num array and for loop was just an active wait,

try it now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                //call for input
                System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                int val = in.nextInt();
                int[] num = new int[3];
                if(val<=99) // is not a 3 digit number
                   return;

                int i =2;
                while (val > 0) {
                   num[i]=(val%10);
                   val = val / 10;
                   i--;
                }
                System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + (num[0] + num[1]+ num[2]));
                System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + num[2] +""+ num[1]+""+ num[0]);

            }
```

With input 1 - 2 -3 gives you:

```
Please Enter a 3-digit number..
1
2
3
The Sum of the numbers is 6
The Reverse of the numbers is 321
```

Comment: Do you think the `System.out.println()` statements will work, won't they simply concatenate, (even if somehow we get the contents at each index say 1, 2, 3), to 123, instead of showing it's sum ?

Comment: please see changes. I concatenate numbers with string in order to avoid the sum of numbers :)

Comment: sorry my friend but i don't understand what you are asking me.. System.out.format("Sum : %d%n", (num[0] + num[1] + num[2])) is a good way to print content but it is the same if you want to concatenate it

Comment: LOL, my bad, I just woke up and sat in front of my PC, forgot to refresh the page, to see the updated edits :-)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. but now it is asking me to input 3 different times. I need to work with only 1 input

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    int rev = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        int rem = n % 10;
        sum += rem;
        rev = rev * 10 + rem;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sum);
    System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + rev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way.

- it uses `StringBuilder` to store the values.
- checks to ensure the number is only a three digit number
- and re-prompts if an incorrect value is entered.

```
// call for input
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");

int val = 0;
boolean expr;
do {
    val = in.nextInt();
    expr = val < 99 || val > 999;
    if (expr) {
        System.out.println(val + " is not a three digit number");
        System.out.println("Please try again");
    }
} while (expr);


StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int sum = 0;
while (val > 0) {
    int d = val % 10;
    sum += d;
    sb.append(d);
    val /= 10;
}
System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sum);
System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + sb);
```

Possible output.

```
Please Enter a 3-digit number..
12
12 is not a three digit number
Please try again
32
32 is not a three digit number
Please try again
4545
4545 is not a three digit number
Please try again
433
The Sum of the numbers is 10
The Reverse of the numbers is 334
```